# Solvent interaction with thermal paper

Tags: everyday-chemistry, heat, solvents

If you place a piece of paper created by a laser printer, *e.g.* fax paper or some receipts, on top of a piece of normal paper you have drawn on with a Bic Marking 2300 permanent marker, the image transfers to the fax/receipt paper? Do any non-toxic solvents heat up as they evaporate? If so, would that explain the reaction between the paper and ink?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. But I know one thing: Evaporation is an endothermic process, so anything that evaporates has to gain heat in some way in order for it to evaporate.